# CSS files are not loading in Laravel view

Tags: css, laravel, nginx

**in the custom.blade.php file, css is linked:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('assets/bootstrap-4.1.3/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```

**it generates this location:**

```
http://localhost.laravel/assets/bootstrap-4.1.3/bootstrap.min.css
```

**but in this URL don't get the CSS file, I get error:** 
[image]

**Server document_root for laravel app is:**

```
/var/www/laravel/public
```

**Here is the  directory map:**

[image]

**here is the server configuration file:**
[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/an-amin/2a28a9e223047bebdc59b0fc2134a806)

Comment: try with href="{{ asset('assets/bootstrap-4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}"

Comment: your path for file is wrong. css folder is missing

Comment: didn't noticed that, now it's working. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS files not loading is related to an error in the file path. You forgot the `css` folder inside the `bootstrap-*` folder

```
{{ asset('assets/bootstrap-4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
```

The error shown in the screenshot is more related to a view not being found or an url/ route not defined.

Comment: oops! sometimes a silly mistake ruins some hours! It's working now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need URL and you are missing css directory.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/bootstrap-4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `css` folder part in your path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/bootstrap-4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
                                                                  ^^^^
```